# Is there any way to reduce more than the minimum width that browsers allow?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox

**Operation System: Windows 10**
**Screen resolution: 1366x768**

I'm trying to make the browsers even smaller in width, but they won't let me pull more to the side than this amount below, `Google Chrome` on the left and `Firefox` on the right. Is there any way to remove this block and lessen more than that?

Note: My problem is screen space on my monitor, so I needed to be able to shrink a little more the browser's.

The idea is to increase this black space between browsers and have more freedom to adjust the width without blocking the minimum.

[image]

Comment: What device/operating system?  Edit tags.  Maybe they are alergic to each other!

Comment: Ok @StainlessSteelRat, is Windows 10 mate!

Comment: Edit your tags!

Comment: Edited and added Windows 10 in tags, thanks for the tip @StainlessSteelRat !

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but you can make the viewport smaller by using the Responsive Design mode: firefox, there is an icon at upper right in the dev tools (right+click > inspect) (or use ctlr+shift+m). This will allow you to set the viewport width to e.g. 300. Useful for mobile previews. Chrome has this too, but not sure about the key-chord. Does not affect min width of the application however.

Comment: Hi @Yorik Actually my problem is screen space on my monitor, so I needed to be able to shrink a little more. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: I had a feeling, but threw it out there anyway. No problem.,

Comment: Firefox may have options in `about:config` and chromium based browsers in  `chrome:prefs` `chrome:flags`. NOTE!! Be a bit careful with settings in those locations. They aren't hidden just for fun...

Comment: What are the dimensions of your screen?  What device?

Comment: What graphics card do you have?  It appears that both NVidia and AMD have hacks which can allow you to set the screen size greater then the resolution of your monitor.  ith the appropriate video driver you may be able to force your screen to a multiple of the native resolution and then use your browsers at normal (you may need to increase font sizes etc on Windows though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may cause both Chrome and Firefox to open a reduced window by
launching a narrow adjustable browser window from JavaScript.

Here is the HTML page you could use:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('your_url_here', '','width=320,height=480')">Open!</a>
```

This will display a simple page with a link named "Open!".
Clicking on the link will open a new browser window that can be resized more
than the usual browser page.

In my experiments, I managed to reduce Firefox to a width of about
290 pixels. Chrome I managed to reduce to about 200 pixels.

---

Another method for Chrome is to use the extension
[OSX Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/osx-resizer/aopgpanbkndckicpnnnaeiebllepdldc).

Clicking the extension's icon will reopen the current page in a new
adjustable window that I managed to reduce to 176 pixels.

---

Still another method for Chrome is to use the Developer Tools
and dock them to right.

The docking is done by opening the Developer Tools and clicking the
three-point menu icon:

[image]

Once the Developer Tools are docked on the right, you may drag the
in-between separator to resize the page that is displayed on
the left.

The minimum I managed to reduce it this way was to 150 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell how small your browser is from the screenshot but I use tool like [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) which let me split my ultrawide monitor into a few virtual screens. With that, I can then press a hot key and moved Firefox into that small screen and it resize automatically. I believe that is a way to squeeze it in.

Another tool I use is [Divvy](https://mizage.com/windivvy/), when triggered, shows my screen in grid and I move my mouse to draw a box to indicate a screen resize size that I need. I can make Firefox really tiny with this.

Picture below is taken from the 27" monitor, not an ultra-wide and you can see how small the Firefox window is.
[image]

I haven't tried this but, in theory, it should be the same - you can install Windows PowerToys which come with an app called Fancy Zone which allows you to create zones around your screen which you can then drop an application into it by pressing SHIFT and dragging you app into the zone. This will automatically resize your application into the size of the zone which you predefined.

Comment: Hi @ringgit malaysia As soon as I get home, I'll take the test in the three options to learn and analyze if it solves my problem, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Good luck. Perhaps you can try Power Toy option first since it is free. Divvy has a trial, if I am not wrong but it is not expensive if turns out useful. DisplayFusion could be a bit pricey but, this is a tool you definitely need if you have multi-monitor setup.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, you can use `userChrome.css` to override the minimum width.

1. Go to `about:config` and set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to true.
2. [Find your user profile.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) The folder should be named something like `30t5gfdj.default-release` or `30t5gfdj.default`.
3. In the user profile folder, create a folder named `chrome`. In `chrome`, create a file named `userChrome.css`. So the full path should end with something like `Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/30t5gfdj.default-release/chrome/userChrome.css`.
4. Once `userChrome.css` is filled in, restart the browser to apply the changes.

This is the contents of my `userChrome.css` file:

```css
@namespace html url("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

:root {
  min-width: 1px !important;
}
```

Comment: Does this fix have a Chrome counterpart?